# Print functions in scipy nonlinear optimization

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

In my code I am optimizing total cost of all years. I wanted to also print the alc results for the optimal solution but it's quite "complicated" as you can see in the print section. I had to rewrite and define the alc calulcations AGAIN within that loop. It is not a big problem in this code cause its not so big and only alc I want to print. But I have changed my original code a bit because of my job - so there are more calculations and functions like baseline in this code that I want to print. Is there not an easier way to print it?

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the objective function
def objective_function(variables):
    Q = variables[:8]  # Production amounts for years 2023 to 2030
    Q_im = variables[8:]  # Import amounts for years 2023 to 2030

    # INPUT
    #PVC
    price = [350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 395, 395, 395]
    import_price = [360, 370, 390, 400, 380, 390, 410, 360]

    HAL_1 = 366134
    HAL_2 = (1619446 + Q[0]) / 5


    # PVC
    PVC = [price[i] * 1.5 for i in range(8)]

    # Calculate the ALC values
    ALC = []
    for i in range(8):
        if i == 0:
            alc = ((450000 + 460000)/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        elif i == 1:
            alc = ((460000 + Q[0])/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        elif i == 2:
            alc = (((Q[i - 1] + Q[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        else:
            alc = (((Q[i - 1] + Q[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_2) / HAL_2
        ALC.append(alc)

    # Calculate the baseline values based on ALC
    baseline = []
    for i, alc in enumerate(ALC):
        if i <= 3:
            if alc <= -0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_1 * (1 + alc))
            elif -0.15 < alc < 0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_1)
            else:
                baseline.append(HAL_1 * (1 + alc))
        else:
            if alc <= -0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_2 * (1 + alc))
            elif -0.15 < alc < 0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_2)
            else:
                baseline.append(HAL_2 * (1 + alc))
  

    # Calculate the free allowances based on the baseline and EU benchmark
    free = [baseline[i] * 1.5 * price[i] for i in range(8)]
    total_cost_year = [PVC[i]*Q[i] - free[i] + import_price[i] * Q_im[i] for i in range(8)]
    total_cost = sum(total_cost_year)

    return total_cost

    # Define the constraints
def constraint(variables):
    Q = variables[:8]
    Q_im = variables[8:]

    constraints = []
    for i in range(8):
        constraints.append(Q[i] + Q_im[i] - 500000)
        constraints.append(700000 - (Q[i] + Q_im[i]))

    return constraints


# Define the initial guess
initial_guess = [0] * 16

# Define the bounds for variables
bounds = [(0, None)] * 16

# Solve the optimization problem
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, bounds=bounds, constraints={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint})

# Extract the optimal solution
optimal_solution = result.x
Q_optimal = optimal_solution[:8]
Q_im_optimal = optimal_solution[8:]

# Print the optimal solution and cost per year
for i, year in enumerate(range(2023, 2031)):
    HAL_1 = 366134
    HAL_2 = (1619446 + Q_optimal[0]) / 5

    print(f"Year: {year}")
    print(f"Production amount: {Q_optimal[i]}")
    print(f"Import amount: {Q_im_optimal[i]}")
    print(f"Cost: {objective_function(optimal_solution)}")

    if year == 2023:
        alc = ((450000 + 460000)/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
    elif year == 2024:
        alc = ((460000 + Q_optimal[0])/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
    elif year == 2025:
        alc = (((Q_optimal[i - 1] + Q_optimal[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_1) / HAL_1
    else:
        alc = (((Q_optimal[i - 1] + Q_optimal[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_2) / HAL_2

    print(f"ALC: {alc}")
    print(HAL_2)
    print()
```

if I write print(alc) or print(baseline) it just says: nameerror: name not defined.

Comment: Does my solution answer your question?

Comment: omg yes thank you!! I have another problem with my code tho: I does not find the optimal solution..... I plot the exact same calculations in excel so its more user friendly to work with, and then I can easily see what I need to do get the costs lower...

Comment: That's a separate question than this one, so I recommend posting a new question (only if you cannot figure out the issue; don't post a question before trying everything, like searching online, watching videos, and reading the documentation). For now, if my solution fixed the posted issue you can click the gray check next to my solution to accept it.

Comment: thank you so much jared :) really appreciate it and that you took your time to understand and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not the most elegant way to do this, but you can make your objective function return the `ALC` list. Since the optimizer only wants a single return, you can create a `lambda` function that evaluates your objective and only returns the `total_cost`.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# Define the objective function
def objective_function_with_ALC(variables):
    Q = variables[:8]  # Production amounts for years 2023 to 2030
    Q_im = variables[8:]  # Import amounts for years 2023 to 2030

    # INPUT
    # PVC
    price = [350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 395, 395, 395]
    import_price = [360, 370, 390, 400, 380, 390, 410, 360]

    HAL_1 = 366134
    HAL_2 = (1619446 + Q[0]) / 5

    # PVC
    PVC = [price[i] * 1.5 for i in range(8)]

    # Calculate the ALC values
    ALC = []
    for i in range(8):
        if i == 0:
            alc = ((450000 + 460000)/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        elif i == 1:
            alc = ((460000 + Q[0])/2 - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        elif i == 2:
            alc = (((Q[i - 1] + Q[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_1) / HAL_1
        else:
            alc = (((Q[i - 1] + Q[i - 2]) / 2) - HAL_2) / HAL_2
        ALC.append(alc)

    # Calculate the baseline values based on ALC
    baseline = []
    for i, alc in enumerate(ALC):
        if i <= 3:
            if alc <= -0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_1 * (1 + alc))
            elif -0.15 < alc < 0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_1)
            else:
                baseline.append(HAL_1 * (1 + alc))
        else:
            if alc <= -0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_2 * (1 + alc))
            elif -0.15 < alc < 0.15:
                baseline.append(HAL_2)
            else:
                baseline.append(HAL_2 * (1 + alc))

    # Calculate the free allowances based on the baseline and EU benchmark
    free = [baseline[i] * 1.5 * price[i] for i in range(8)]
    total_cost_year = [PVC[i]*Q[i] 
                       - free[i] 
                       + import_price[i] * Q_im[i] for i in range(8)]
    total_cost = sum(total_cost_year)

    return total_cost, ALC


# Define the constraints
def constraint(variables):
    Q = variables[:8]
    Q_im = variables[8:]

    constraints = []
    for i in range(8):
        constraints.append(Q[i] + Q_im[i] - 500000)
        constraints.append(700000 - (Q[i] + Q_im[i]))

    return constraints


# Define the initial guess
initial_guess = [0] * 16

# Define the bounds for variables
bounds = [(0, None)] * 16


objective_function = lambda x: objective_function_with_ALC(x)[0]

# Solve the optimization problem
result = minimize(objective_function,
                  initial_guess,
                  bounds=bounds,
                  constraints={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint})

# Extract the optimal solution
optimal_solution = result.x
Q_optimal = optimal_solution[:8]
Q_im_optimal = optimal_solution[8:]

cost, ALC = objective_function_with_ALC(optimal_solution)

# Print the optimal solution and cost per year
for i, year in enumerate(range(2023, 2031)):
    HAL_2 = (1619446 + Q_optimal[0]) / 5

    print(f"Year: {year}")
    print(f"Production amount: {Q_optimal[i]}")
    print(f"Import amount: {Q_im_optimal[i]}")
    print(f"Cost: {cost}")
    print(f"ALC: {ALC[i]}")
    print(HAL_2)
    print()
```